# How to set up and use Pub/Sub Notifications for Cloud Storage using console wihout CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

If any Storage is updated, would that trigger an event and send a message in Pub/Sub?? Is that possible? When I research over, I can only found CLI command but I want to do this without using CLI.

Comment: Check this https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications

Comment: What do you mean "without CLI". So you prefer what?

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the relevant section of the [Cloud Storage Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes) you will only be able to achieve this using the CLI, the relevant client libraries or the JSON API, as there is no menu within the Cloud Console to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The gsutil CLI has a subcommand, `notification`, that controls Pub/Sub settings. It's documented here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification, or you can type `gsutil help notification`.

To create a pub/sub topic named "mytopic" and attach it to a bucket named "mybucket", you'd use this command:

```
gsutil notification create -f json -t mytopic gs://mybucket
```

Comment: can we create only 1 subscription for all of my cloud storage buckets?

Comment: No, a subscription of a property of a bucket. You can create subscriptions on each bucket that all point to the same topic, though.